# How to provision a bunch of resources using the pyplate macro

Tags: aws-cloudformation

In this learning exercise I want to use a [PyPlate](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-macros/tree/master/PyPlate) script to provision the `BucketA`, `BucketB` and `BucketC` buckets in addition to the `TestBucket`.

Imagine that the BucketNames parameter could be set by a user of this template who would specify a hundred bucket names using UUIDs for example.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: [PyPlate]
Description: A stack that provisions a bunch of s3 buckets based on param names
Parameters:
  BucketNames:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: All bucket names that should be created
    Default: BucketA,BucketB,BucketC
Resources:
  TestBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"

  #!PyPlate
  output = []
  bucket_names = params['BucketNames']
  for name in bucket_names:
    output.append('"' + name + '": {"Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"}')
```

The above when deployed responds with a `Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 15, column 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the accepted answer is functionally correct, there is a better way to approach this.
Essentially PyPlate code recursively reads through all the key-value pairs of the stack and replaces the values with their Python computed values (ie they match the `#!PyPlate` regex). So we need to have a corresponding key to the PyPlate code.

Here's how a combination of PyPlate and Explode would solve the above problem.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: [PyPlate, Explode]
Description: A stack that provisions a bunch of s3 buckets based on param names
Parameters:
  BucketNames:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: All bucket names that should be created
    Default: BucketA,BucketB,BucketC
Mappings: {}
Resources:
  MacroWrapper:
    ExplodeMap: |
      #!PyPlate
      param = "BucketNames"
      mapNamespace = param + "Map"
      template["Mappings"][mapNamespace] = {}
      for bucket in params[param]:
        template["Mappings"][mapNamespace][bucket] = {
          "ResourceName": bucket
        }
      output = mapNamespace
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"

  TestBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
```

This approach is powerful because:

1. You can append resources to an existing template, because you won't tamper with the whole `Resources` block
2. You don't need to rely on hardcoded `Mappings`, as required by Explode. You can drive dynamic logic in Cloudformation.
3. Most of the Cloudformation props/KV's remain in the YAML part, and there is minimal python part which augments to the CFT functionality.

Please be aware of the macro order through - PyPlate needs to be executed before Explode, which is why the order `[PyPlate, Explode]`. The execution is sequential.

If we walk through the source code of PyPlate, it gives us control of more template related variables to work with, namely

- params (stack parameters)
- template (the entire template)
- account_id
- region

I utilised the `template` variable in this case.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: [PyPlate]
Description: A stack that provisions a bunch of s3 buckets based on param names
Parameters:
  BucketNames:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: All bucket names that should be created
    Default: BucketA,BucketB,BucketC
Resources:
  |
    #!PyPlate
    output = {}
    bucket_names = params['BucketNames']
    for name in bucket_names:
      output[name] = {"Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"}
```

[image]

Explanation:

The python code outputs a `dict` object where the key is the bucket name and the value is its configuration:

```py
{'BucketA': {'Type': 'AWS::S3::Bucket'}, 'BucketB': {'Type': 'AWS::S3::Bucket'}}
```

Prior to Macro execution, the YAML template is transformed to JSON format, and because the above is valid JSON data, I can plug it in as value of `Resources`.

(Note that having the hardcoded `TestBucket` won't work with this and I had to remove it)